# Is there any way to convert existing QTP script in to selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, tools

Is there any way to convert existing QTP script in to selenium? if yes then how ? is there any converter to convert or recreation of script is only possible solution for tha?

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically possible but practically too much work, example here of people trying it

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-developers/rq1sQwUIJKM

Comment: +1 for evaluating and re-writing rather than converting them in an automated way.  It's actually a great chance to clean up your existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a similar transition in the past from TestPartner to WatiN.

What we did is we started writing all our new tests in the new framework and just kept executing the old tests in the old tool. When one needed to be updated, we would turn off the old one and write a new one in it's place.

This avoids a huge rewrite, let's you use a new tool as well as leverage your investment in the licenses that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Our Migration from License Tools to Open Source (MiLTOS), a service offering that allows customers to migrate from the licensed tool Quick Test Professional (QTP) to open source tool – Selenium (Java). This offering reduces the use of licensed tools, thereby minimizing the costs incurred on licensed tools.